# "jboss.deployment.subunit. undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.ws.MyAppWS.<init>()

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jboss, wildfly-18

When I try to deploy my maven project using `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` and then try to upload the war file manually this is what I am seeing:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"myapp-ear.ear\".\"myapp-ws.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.ws.MyappWS.<init>()
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.ws.MyAppWS.<init>()"}}
```

If I try to deploy using the command line, this is what I am seeing:

https://pastebin.com/1CkvEL1f

Here is what I see in the `wildfly` console:

https://pastebin.com/CHhHMpMZ

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found it, I had put this on web.xml:

```
<servlet-class>org.ws.MyappWS</servlet-class>
```

But needed to change it to this:

```
<servlet-class>ec.ws.MyappWSImpl</servlet-class>
```